# In Windows Services I have to hook the handler of 3rd Party Dll

Tags: windows, service

on assigning the static function in Class to the event handler of 3rd party is not kicking . Maybe the service is not in idle state as in the console application with While(1){sleep(1000)}. How to achieve the same.

EDIT:

I am creating one services which will receive certain error details from 3rd Party dll. Suppose 3rd Party Vendor provides X ,Y & Z status of devices if we hook as evt_handler to 3rd party function pointer.say `handle->funcpointer=evt_handler` and start monitor function of 3rd party.But since the Services just initialize in OnStart and exit.it seems the SCM doesn't know that an event_handler exist. so how to keep the Services in idle loop. If I make simple console application then works with while(1) for idle and the event handled at event handler .But I want to put the same in services.

This doesn't work in Windows Services program

```
OnStart()
{
    hdl=LoadLibrary("x.dll"); //LOading of library is happening
    Monitor=(Monitor)GetProcAddress(hdl,"Monitor")
    x.funcptr=event_handler;
    MOnitor(x);
}

void event_handler()
{
    case X:
    case Y:
    Case Z:
}
```

this works in console application

```
main()
{ 
    hdl=LoadLibrary("x.dll"); //LOading of library is happening 
    Monitor=(Monitor)GetProcAddress(hdl,"Monitor") 
    x.funcptr=event_handler; 
    MOnitor(x);
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's extremely unclear what exactly are you doing and what is your problem. Please provide more details, and some code if possible.

Comment: I am creating one services which will receive certain error details from 3rd Party dll. Suppose 3rd Party Vendor provides X ,Y & Z status of devices if we hook as evt_handler to 3rd party function pointer.say handle->funcpointer=evt_handler and start monitor function of 3rd party.But since the Services just initialize in OnStart and exit.it seems the SCM doesn't know that an event_handler exist. so how to keep the Services in idle loop. If I make simple console application then works with while(1) for idle and the event handled at event handler .But I want to put the same in services.

Comment: This doesn't work
in Windows Services program
OnStart()
{
hdl=LoadLibrary("x.dll");
//LOading of library is happening
Monitor=(Monitor)GetProcAddress(hdl,"Monitor")

x.funcptr=event_handler;

MOnitor(x);

}
void event_handler()
{
case X:
case Y:
Case Z:
}

this works
in console application
main()
{
hdl=LoadLibrary("x.dll");
//LOading of library is happening
Monitor=(Monitor)GetProcAddress(hdl,"Monitor")

x.funcptr=event_handler;

MOnitor(x);
while(1)
{
sleep(100);
}
}

Comment: *Slightly* better, but still, it's quite hard to figure out what's going on. Say, in the console app, does the sleep loop even run, or does the Monitor() call block? Check that. If the sleep loop runs, do the event_handler calls come on worker threads?